# How do I use an incremented index in Perl's map function?

Tags: perl, dictionary, indexing, increment

I'd like to use an incremented index in Perl, in the map function. The code I have is:

```
use strict;

my $ord = "46.15,18.59,47.45,21.14";
my $c = 1;

my @a = split(",",$ord);
my $str = join("\n", map "x($c++) := $_;", @a);
print $str;
```

This outputs:

> x(1++) := 46.15;
>   x(1++) := 18.59;
>   x(1++) := 47.45;
>   x(1++) := 21.14;

Instead of the x(1++), I would like x(1), x(2), etc.
How can I reach it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `map`. You placed Perl code inside a string literal and hoped it would get executed.

Replace

```
map "x($c++) := $_;",
```

with

```
map { ++$c; "x($c) := $_;" }
```

---

Also, you are missing a trailing newline. Fixed:

```
my $str = join "", map { ++$c; "x($c) := $_;\n" } @a;
print $str;
```

or

```
print map { ++$c; "x($c) := $_;\n" } @a;
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of mapping the array, you can map your count, and not need a separate variable:

```
my $str = join("\n", map "x($_) := $a[$_-1];", 1..@a);
```

Or, to include a trailing newline:

```
my $str = join('', map "x($_) := $a[$_-1];\n", 1..@a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that concatenating is the answer:

```
my $str = join("\n", map "x(".$c++.") := $_;", @a);
```

Comment: It is _an_ answer.  But if you want all lines to have `\n` then append it to each string in `map` expression, `map ... ") := $_;\n"` and use `join ''`. This way the last one has no `\n`.  Or `print $str, "\n"` of course (what `say` does for you)